# Does imageField.save() and add() save the whole model in django?

Tags: django, model

I just experienced, that my `model.save()` command was needless, because obviously that has already been done by `image.save()` and also `childs.add()`

```
model = Model()
child = Child()
model.name = 'Test'
model.image.save(file)
model.childs.add(child)
model.save() # is not necessary
```

Usually this shouldn't even work with a new entry, because the add function wont work without a pk. But it looks like the `image.save()` method did not only move/upload the imagefile but also saved the whole model to the DB. The same seems to be done by `childs.add()`, because this information is also updated without calling `model.save()`.

I always thought, that updating the database is only done when calling `model.save()`, obviously I was wrong or where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as documented. There's even a highlighted warning about it in the docs.

> **Warning**
>
> Two methods of this class, save() and delete(), default to saving the
>   model object of the associated FieldFile in the database.

By default [`FileField.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) (which ImageField inherits from) will save both the file to the file storage and the model instance. This ensures that the state of the database and the state of the file storage is consistent. You can override this by using the named argument `save=False` in the `FileField.save()` method.

[`RelatedManager.add()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) does not save your model instance. But it will update the relation in the database, which is represented in the other model as a foreign key or in an intermediary join table. If you have changes to other fields in you instance, you must use `save()` to persist those changes.